# SQL query taking very long to execute

Tags: sql-server

I have two versions of the same query which I'm trying to execute on `SQL Server 2008`.

Version 1:

```
select 
    count(a.ordernumber) as Orders, 
    sum(b.agentfees) as AgentFees, 
    sum(a.revenue) as Revenue,
    CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date) as Date
from 
    orders a 
join 
    [DC-SQL-V2].FaxFile.dbo.[agent fees] b on a.ordernumber = b.fforder
where 
    a.closeoutdate >= '2014-01-01'
    and b.dtcreated >= '2014-01-01'
    and a.closeoutdate < '2015-01-01'
    and b.dtcreated < '2015-01-01'
    and a.processserving = 1
    and a.branchno = '116'
group by
    CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date)
order by
    CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date)
```

Version 1 takes around 3 hours to finish which is obviously insane. So I created Version 2 in which I tried to filter the tables first before joining them, but this still takes pretty long (2 hours and still going).

Version 2:

```
select 
    count(a.ordernumber) as Orders, 
    sum(b.agentfees) as AgentFees, 
    sum(a.revenue) as Revenue,
    CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date) as Date
from 
    (select 
         ordernumber, revenue, closeoutdate, processserving, branchno
     from 
         ORDERS
     where 
         closeoutdate >= '2014-01-01'
         and closeoutdate < '2015-01-01'
         and branchno = '116'
         and processserving = 1) a 
join 
    (select 
         agentfees, fforder, dtcreated
     from 
         [DC-SQL-V2].FaxFile.dbo.[agent fees]
     where 
         dtcreated >= '2014-01-01'
         and dtcreated < '2015-01-01') b on a.ordernumber = b.fforder
group by
    CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' +  CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date)
order by
    CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date)
```

Here are some additional details:

```
select count(*) from [DC-SQL-V2].FaxFile.dbo.[agent fees]

779531

select count(*) from ORDERS

3466648
```

Here are the clustered columns for both tables (among others that I'm not selecting):

ORDERS:

```
BranchNo
Closeoutdate
ProcessServing
```

AGENT FEES:

Nothing I'm selecting is clustered

Would someone please be able to suggest how I can improve the performance of my queries?

Comment: What indexes do you have on these tables?

Comment: I would recommend to review the execution plan and also check whether the joined columns are indexed.

Comment: You will never count orders where dtcreated and closeoutdate are in different years.

Comment: Always look at the estimated execution plan to help identify problems and bottle-necks, and identify where additional indexes might help you (or additional INCLUDE columns on existing indexes). Tools like "SQL Sentry Plan Explorer" (free) can help even more.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming [DC-SQL-V2] is a remote, linked server, I'd recommend bringing that data local first.

```
/* Making broad assumptions here. Substitute correct data types */
CREATE TABLE #tmpAgentFees (
    agentfees money, 
    fforder int, 
    dtcreated datetime
);

INSERT INTO #tmpAgentFees
    (agentfees, fforder, dtcreated)
    SELECT agentfees, fforder, dtcreated
        FROM [DC-SQL-V2].FaxFile.dbo.[agent fees]
        WHERE dtcreated >= '2014-01-01'
            AND dtcreated < '2015-01-01';

/* Optionally, add an index to perhaps help performance of the join */
CREATE INDEX IX_tmpAgentFees_fforder 
    ON #tmpAgentFees(fforder)
    INCLUDE (agentfees, dtcreated);

select count(a.ordernumber) as Orders, sum(b.agentfees) as AgentFees, sum(a.revenue) as Revenue,
CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date) as Date
from orders a 
    join #tmpAgentFees b
        on a.ordernumber = b.fforder
where a.closeoutdate >= '2014-01-01'
    and a.closeoutdate < '2015-01-01'
    and a.processserving=1
    and a.branchno='116'
group by
CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date)
order by
CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date)
```

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned, this is PROD environment, I can't bring remote data in.

Comment: @Patthebug Sure you can. You're just putting the results of your subquery from Version 2 into a temp table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I've also updated the question with index info.

Answer (score 1):

There are some general hints

1. use SQL Server Profiler to find the most costly part
2. use an index on join column `fforder`
3. `CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date)` is repeated again and again, if it is possible create a computer column in your table and store the value and create an index on this new column with include in index option on
4. if 3 is not possible use drive table for example as below

   ```
   select * from
   (
       select col1,col2,..,CAST('1/' + CAST(DATEPART(Month, a.closeoutdate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, a.closeoutdate)  as varchar) as Date) from table1 ) drivedTable
   join .....
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The costly part is where you are getting detail data from the foreign server and then summarizing it. You should summarize it their and then only bring that back. It is not clear to me how "dtcreated" and "closeoutdate" are related?

Below I summarized the data by month and then brought it over to the local server. So only 12 rows are coming over instead of one per order. This may not be what you want if the fee should be counted in the "closeoutdate" month. But your code had a problem where it would never count an order or fee if there dates were in different years. (Need to clarify what is needed with that.)

```
select 
    a.CloseMonth,
    a.Orders,
    b.AgentFees
    a.Revenue
   from 

   (select year(closeoutdate) * 100 + month(closeoutdate) as CloseMonth,
    count(a.ordernumber) as Orders, 
    sum(a.revenue) as Revenue
    from orders
         where closeoutdate >= '2014-01-01'
         and closeoutdate < '2015-01-01'
         and branchno = '116'
         and processserving = 1
         group by year(closeoutdate) * 100 + month(closeoutdate)) as a 

    join 
    (select year(dtcreated) * 100 + month(dtcreated) as FeeMonth,
        sum(agentfees) AgentFees
     from [DC-SQL-V2].FaxFile.dbo.[agent fees]
         where 
             dtcreated >= '2014-01-01'
             and dtcreated < '2015-01-01'
             group by year(dtcreated) * 100 + month(dtcreated)) b 
    on a.CloseMonth = b.FeeMonth
    order by a.CloseMonth
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know my code wouldn't count some orders and I'm okay with that as long as the query execution is fast. I'll try it out.

Comment: The execution of this query is pretty fast but I would like to join on ORDERNUMBER and FFORDER.